# Installing opencv for python3

Tags: opencv, python-3.x, cmake

Has anyone tried to install opencv for python3?. As stated here http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide its support status is unknown. So I want to try it:

I have downloaded the sources for OpenCV-2.3.1. But cmake reports.

> --     Python interpreter:         /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin/python3 -B (ver
>   3.2)
>
> --     Python numpy:               NO (Python wrappers will not be generated)

I do have numpy (version 1.6.0) installed in python3 but cmake does not find it. I am using Mac OSX 10.6 Any ideas?

**Update**

I just saw one more thing of the cmake output that might be helpful

> -- Found PythonInterp: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin/python3 (found
>   version "3.2")
>
> -- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython2.6.dylib    File "", line 1
>
> ```
> from distutils.sysconfig import *; print get_python_lib()
>
>                                                       ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax   File "", line 1
>
> ```
> import os; os.environ['DISTUTILS_USE_SDK']='1'; import numpy.distutils; print
> ```
>
> numpy.distutils.misc_util.get_numpy_include_dirs()[0]
>
> ```
>                                                                     ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax   File "", line 1
>
> ```
> import sphinx; print sphinx.__version__
>
>                           ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Notice that it found 3.2 but then libpython2.6 ??

Any ideas?

Comment: Note it also needs to find the development headers in an include directory, although I don't know where that should be.

Comment: Sorry to be asking a bit too late but did you manage to have success with your endeavour?

Comment: @Ishbir: Not really, but I haven't really tried in the last 6 months.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV for Python 3.x under Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489867/opencv-for-python-3-x-under-windows)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the moment OpenCV supports Python 2.x only. OpenCV (including OpenCV 2.4) does not compiles with Python 3.x.

Python3 support is already in wishlist for future versions of OpenCV. But currently there are no activities in this direction and you are welcome to create and contribute a patch resolving the compatibility issues.

Comment: Actually, I changed some of the cmake files to make them python3 compatible (basically adding parenthesis to print). Now cmake goes through. make does not finish but it seems that there all small thing. The question is which minimum python version you want to support? Dropping support < 2.6 will be great in order to have a single codebase.

Comment: Python3 is supported now from open cv 3.0 onwards

Answer (score 5):

Use the pip application.

On ubuntu:

`sudo apt install python3-pip`

and so, on command line:

`pip3 install --upgrade pip`

`pip3 install opencv-python`

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 14

Answer (score 4):

I got the thing to at least build and install. It can load the cv2 module just fine. Haven't tested too much though.

Details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21212023/3075814