# Python3 Pillow Get all pixels on a line

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I need to get the pixel values along a line, I'm using Python3 and Pillow. In opencv there is such a thing as a [LineIterator](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#lineiterator) which will return all of the appropriate pixels between two points, but I haven't found anything like that in Pillow's docs.

I'm using Pillow because I had originally saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315021/installing-opencv-for-python3) post which said that python3 didn't have opencv support, I know that it's from 2012 but that seems to be confirmed by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953273/install-opencv-for-python-3-3) post which I believe is from this year, given that there is no year on the posts. But when I run pip3.2 search opencv I can see a pyopencv but am unable to install it, it says that it could not find an appropriate version (probably a python2.x to python3.x issue).

My preferred solutions are ordered as follows:

1. A way to properly install opencv for python3 (preferably opencv 2.4.8)
2. A way to get the pixels of a line using just Pillow
3. Simple solutions that don't involve extra libraries (numpy/scipy)
4. Everything else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up going with a straight python solution based on [Xiaolin Wu's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu's_line_algorithm)

```
def interpolate_pixels_along_line(x0, y0, x1, y1):
    """Uses Xiaolin Wu's line algorithm to interpolate all of the pixels along a
    straight line, given two points (x0, y0) and (x1, y1)

    Wikipedia article containing pseudo code that function was based off of:
        http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu's_line_algorithm
    """
    pixels = []
    steep = abs(y1 - y0) > abs(x1 - x0)

    # Ensure that the path to be interpolated is shallow and from left to right
    if steep:
        t = x0
        x0 = y0
        y0 = t

        t = x1
        x1 = y1
        y1 = t

    if x0 > x1:
        t = x0
        x0 = x1
        x1 = t

        t = y0
        y0 = y1
        y1 = t

    dx = x1 - x0
    dy = y1 - y0
    gradient = dy / dx  # slope

    # Get the first given coordinate and add it to the return list
    x_end = round(x0)
    y_end = y0 + (gradient * (x_end - x0))
    xpxl0 = x_end
    ypxl0 = round(y_end)
    if steep:
        pixels.extend([(ypxl0, xpxl0), (ypxl0 + 1, xpxl0)])
    else:
        pixels.extend([(xpxl0, ypxl0), (xpxl0, ypxl0 + 1)])

    interpolated_y = y_end + gradient

    # Get the second given coordinate to give the main loop a range
    x_end = round(x1)
    y_end = y1 + (gradient * (x_end - x1))
    xpxl1 = x_end
    ypxl1 = round(y_end)

    # Loop between the first x coordinate and the second x coordinate, interpolating the y coordinates
    for x in range(xpxl0 + 1, xpxl1):
        if steep:
            pixels.extend([(math.floor(interpolated_y), x), (math.floor(interpolated_y) + 1, x)])

        else:
            pixels.extend([(x, math.floor(interpolated_y)), (x, math.floor(interpolated_y) + 1)])

        interpolated_y += gradient

    # Add the second given coordinate to the given list
    if steep:
        pixels.extend([(ypxl1, xpxl1), (ypxl1 + 1, xpxl1)])
    else:
        pixels.extend([(xpxl1, ypxl1), (xpxl1, ypxl1 + 1)])

    return pixels
```

Comment: note that, in half of cases (depending on angle of the line), this will actually return the points _backwards_.  it also overshoots by one pixel much of the time

Answer (score 5):

I tried the code suggested by @Rick but it did not work. Then I went to [Xiaolin's code](https://github.com/sachinruk/xiaolinwu/blob/master/xiaolinwu.m)  written in Matlab and translated it into Python:

```
def xiaoline(x0, y0, x1, y1):

        x=[]
        y=[]
        dx = x1-x0
        dy = y1-y0
        steep = abs(dx) < abs(dy)

        if steep:
            x0,y0 = y0,x0
            x1,y1 = y1,x1
            dy,dx = dx,dy

        if x0 > x1:
            x0,x1 = x1,x0
            y0,y1 = y1,y0

        gradient = float(dy) / float(dx)  # slope

        """ handle first endpoint """
        xend = round(x0)
        yend = y0 + gradient * (xend - x0)
        xpxl0 = int(xend)
        ypxl0 = int(yend)
        x.append(xpxl0)
        y.append(ypxl0) 
        x.append(xpxl0)
        y.append(ypxl0+1)
        intery = yend + gradient

        """ handles the second point """
        xend = round (x1);
        yend = y1 + gradient * (xend - x1);
        xpxl1 = int(xend)
        ypxl1 = int (yend)
        x.append(xpxl1)
        y.append(ypxl1) 
        x.append(xpxl1)
        y.append(ypxl1 + 1)

        """ main loop """
        for px in range(xpxl0 + 1 , xpxl1):
            x.append(px)
            y.append(int(intery))
            x.append(px)
            y.append(int(intery) + 1)
            intery = intery + gradient;

        if steep:
            y,x = x,y

        coords=zip(x,y)

        return coords
```

Finally, I used the above code with a script for plotting:

```
    import numpy as np 
    import demo_interpolate_pixels_along_line as interp 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    A=np.zeros((21,21))

    p0=(5,15)
    p1=(20,5)

    coords=interp.xiaoline(p0[0],p0[1],p1[0],p1[1])
    for c in coords:
        A[c]=1

    A[p0]=0.2
    A[p1]=0.8

    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(A.T,interpolation='none',
                    origin='lower',
                    cmap='gist_earth_r',
                    vmin=0,
                    vmax=1)
    plt.grid(which='major')
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    plt.text(p0[0],p0[1],'0',fontsize=18,color='r')
    plt.text(p1[0],p1[1],'1',fontsize=18,color='r')
    plt.show()
```

...I do not have enough reputation to post images :(

Comment: Glad you were able to find a solution, but what was it about my code that didn't work? Was there a mistake or is it just something has changed since I posted it? Just wondering if there's something that I should update about my solution.

Comment: Within the minor issues is adding `import math` and convert `xpxl0` and `xpxl1` to `int`, otherwise you get a `TypeError` message (range expect an int). 

Within the major issues, if I have a 100x100 grid and try to plot a line from (10,70) to (80,80), I get a line from (10,70) to (80,70). I'm not sure why is this but it was the reason I went to the original code in Matlab.

Comment: note that, in half of cases (depending on angle of the line), this will actually return the points _backwards_.  it also overshoots by one pixel much of the time

Comment: Also, the code ```x.append(xpxl1);y.append(ypxl1);x.append(xpxl1);y.append(ypxl1 + 1)``` can be placed after the main loop so that the end points are actually at the end of the resulting list.

Answer (score 2):

You should try the development version 3.0-dev of opencv. The current 2.4 series will not support python3. check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20953731/566035).

When using pillow, [Image.getpixel](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html) will give you the pixel value. So, you could simply interpolate two points in pure python and give all these indexes to Image.getpixel. I do not know an elegant pure python implementation of interpolation to get all the pixels on a line.

So, if this is too much hassle, you could use numpy/matplotlib to get it done easier (lazier). You could use [matplotlib.path.Path](http://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html) to create a path and use its contains_points methods to go through all the possible points (for example use numpy.meshgrid to get all pixel coordinates of the binding box defined by these two points).

Answer (score 2):

A solution in scikit-image for readers in need of something off the shelf:

```
skimage.measure.profile_line(image, start_point, end_point)
```